# Does Python console limit output size

Tags: python, command

I'm trying to execute command in Python like this:

```
os.system('ls')
```

What's interesting is that the output length is limited by the terminal window size where I'm running this python console.

```
>>>os.system('ls -l')
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 hy hy 0 Apr 29 22:30 a.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 hy hy 0 Apr 29 22:31 b.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 hy hy 0 Apr 29 22:31 c.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 hy hy 0 Apr 29 22:31 d.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 hy hy 0 Apr 29 22:31 e.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 hy hy 0 Apr 29 22:31 f.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 hy hy 0 Apr 29 22:31 g.txt
>>>
```

I did that in a directory containing hundreds of files, and intentionally re-size the terminal window very small, it only outputs very few lines which exactly fill the entire window. If I use smaller terminal window, it output even less lines. **Every time it just outputs down to the low boundary of my terminal window.**

It's not that python console hides some output when displaying. I tried using subprocess.Popen() to store the output into a pipe and readlines() the pipe, and got the same result.

But it seems python doesn't do that all the time. I don't got this problem on all machines.

Comment: This certainly isn't supposed to happen, but it sounds more like a bug with your `ls` program than with Python. (Note that `os.system` is just calling calling the C function `system` and `subprocess.Popen` is just calling `pipe`, `fork`, and `exec`, and I can't even imagine what Python could do wrong in calling those that could cause anything like that to happen.

Comment: Could you show us screenshots of this happening, with two different terminal sizes, and listing the same directory?

Comment: The computer I'm using now is fine with 'ls' command in Python. But same problem with commands like 'top'. I tried run top with -b batch mode, it only displays exactly a screen's output instead of all processes' status.

Comment: Have you read the [man page](http://www.unixtop.org/man.shtml) for top? I think you're just seeing the normal behavior; it doesn't list all processes by default, and -b doesn't have anything to do with changing that.

Comment: I added -b flag to run it in batch mode. But its behavior was just like without -b. It's hard to be reproduced on most machines. I only got this problem on one machine.